# how to write DML to Create a partition by integer column in big query SQL

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-bigquery

we have base tables that need to be partitioned the issue in writing it , here sql i used

CREATE TABLE

cp1753.CI_DEV.PT_CI_STEP
(
build_id    INTEGER ,
step_name   STRING  ,
type    STRING  ,
start_time  INTEGER ,
status  STRING  ,
timestamp   INTEGER ,
stop_time   INTEGER ,       )
PARTITION BY
stop_time INTEGER
AS
SELECT

build_id,step_name  ,type, start_time,status,timestamp , stop_time
from
`cp1753.CI_DEV.ci_step`

got error
PARTITION BY expression must be DATE(<timestamp_column>), DATE(<datetime_column>), RANGE_BUCKET(<int64_column>, GENERATE_ARRAY(<int64_value>, <int64_value>[, <int64_value>]))

[Here is the table itself](https://i.stack.imgur.com/B815S.png)

Answer (score 0):

You can't partition by raw integer, you have to partition by [range bucket](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/creating-partitioned-tables#create_an_integer-range_partitioned_table). Keep in mind that you can have up to 4000 partition, If you have 4000 or less different `stop_time` values, you can perform a GENERATE_ARRAY(0,4000,1) for example (if the values are between 0 and 4000)